# InverseFunctionalProperty pointing to multiple different inverse properties

Tags: semantic-web, topbraid-composer

I am playing around with [TopBraid Composer](http://www.topquadrant.com/tools/ide-topbraid-composer-maestro-edition/) to learn how to make ontologies using Semantic Web technologies.

**What I did:**

- I created an ontology of airplanes,
  cities, airports, states etc.
- Now that the ontology is getting a bit complicated, I ran into a problem

**Ontology**

[The graph of my current ontology can be found on my drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7J6K8vSkV2Hd0JzbnB6b2ktMjQ/view?usp=sharing).

**What I want:**

Since I am learning, I thought it would be great to try to have a property hasCity both for the country and the airport. This should result in linking the aiport with the city and also the city with a country only having one property.

**What I tried (and failed to understand)**

1. I modified **the hasCity property to be in the domain Airport**
2. Another modification I did was that **the property hasCity is also a functionalInverseOf hasAirport**

In TopBraid you can run inferences to see what happened with your data. [Included printscreen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7J6K8vSkV2HaXJyOU55YzFCS00/view?usp=sharing)

It seems, that by modifying the hasCity property I stated that Object rdfs:type is also Aiport.

Can somebody, please, point me in the right direction?

[Here is the whole 333 lines of my RDF, if it can help.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7J6K8vSkV2HTnBoYjRmTGd5d0E/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `hasCity` to have domains both `Airport` and `Country`. This means that, for every `Airport` with a `hasCity` filler, the `Airport` is also inferred to be a `Country`. This is unlikely to be what you mean to express.

Also, this assertion is dubious as well - the range of a datatype property is supposed to be a datatype, not a class.

```xml
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="Destination">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#City"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Transportation"/>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Destination</rdfs:label>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```